# Change parent branch to feature branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, feature-branch

I was working on a feature branch in this structure:

```
a -- b -- c -- d           <-- master
     \     \
      \     e -- f         <-- feature
       \
        g                  <-- new_parent
```

But I need to switch my branches to be in this way:

```
a -- b -- c -- d           <-- master
      \
       g                   <-- new_parent
        \
         e -- f            <-- feature
```

Note that my `feature` branch comes from `master` that is **ahead** of  `new_parent` because I rebased it from `master` and `new_parent` will be rebased into `master` once all the work is done in the `feature` branch and rebased to `new_parent`.

I'm not that familiar with git, and I don't want to mess my repo, I read about `git rebase onto` command, but I'm not sure if the below command will do what I'm trying to do.

```
git rebase --onto new_parent feature master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `git rebase --onto new_parent master feature`

Command format from the `man` page:

```
git rebase [--onto <newbase>] [<upstream> [<branch>]]
```

`new_parent` is `newbase` i.e. the point you want to apply your changes to.

`master` is `upstream` i.e. the point from which your changes currently start.

`feature` is obviously `branch` i.e. the branch on which your changes can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough:

```
git rebase --onto g master feature
```

Which roughly translates to: rebase feature branch on top of g discarding all the revisions that belong to master.